# Emmet - Wrap with Abbreviation - Token that represents the wrapped text i.e. {original text}

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I'm attempting to convert a list of URLs into HTML links as lazily as possible:

```
www.annaandsally.com.au
www.babylush.com.au
www.babysgotstyle.com.au
... etc
```

Using wrap in abbreviation, I'd like to do something like: `a[href="http://${1}/"]*`

The expanded abbreviation would result in:

```
<a href="http://www.annaandsally.com.au/">www.annaandsally.com.au</a>
<a href="http://www.babylush.com.au/">www.babylush.com.au</a>
<a href="http://www.babysgotstyle.com.au/">www.babysgotstyle.com.au</a>
... etc
```

**The missing piece of the puzzle is an abbreviation token that represents the text being wrapped.**

Any idea if this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergey from Emmet was kind enough to point me in the right direction. The `$#` token contains the original content:

`a[href="http://$#/"]*>{$#}`

By specifying `$#` as the `href` attribute, the original content is no longer 'wrapped' and must be be reinserted via `{$#}`.

http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#controlling-output-position

Answer (score 1):

If they are already on their own lines (which in the question, they look like they are), a simple Find and Replace with RegEx turned on will work. The Params are as follows:

Find What:

```
(.+)
```

Replace With:

```
<a href=\"http://$1\">$1</a>
```

**Before**

[image: See Here]

**After**

[image]

Comment: I just noticed you tagged the question with emmet. If you need this to be solved via that method, I will remove this as an answer.

Comment: I'd prefer it was an Emmet specific answer, but this certainly works for now. Thanks!