# Sublime Text for windows- Wrap with Abbreviation

Tags: html, sublimetext2, emmet

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645397/emmet-wrap-with-abbreviation-token-that-represents-the-wrapped-text-i-e-or), but it is little bit different. I am using Sublime Text for windows, I want to style the bellow text as unordered list with  tag wrapped inside. I follow the "Wrap with Abbreviation" command as I read from the [documentation site](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/). But as I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> command after selecting the text, I couldn't get the "Enter Wrap wrap abbreviation" input window. I also tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, but rather than showing the "Enter wrap abbreviation" command, it is just allowing me to type the attribute manually.

[When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>]

[image]

[this is the output after <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>]

[image: When I press Alt+Shift+W]![enter image description here]

[and this is the output after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>]

Row Text:

- one
- two
- three
- four

desired output:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="one"> one </a></li>
   <li><a href="two"> two</a></li>
   <li><a href="three"> three</a></li>
   <li><a href="four"> four</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I guess most developers are using sublime in Mac, but I hope some one with windows experience to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctrl+shift+g

```
ul>li*>a[href=$#]{$#}
```

you'll get something like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="one">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="two">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="three">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

which I guess is what you want

If you need that space in the link, just add it to the second curly bracket like this

```
ul>li*>a[href=$#]{ $#}
```

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="one"> one</a></li>
    <li><a href="two"> two</a></li>
    <li><a href="three"> three</a></li>
    <li><a href="four"> four</a></li>
</ul>
```

oh, and some other additional tricks http://www.sitepoint.com/faster-workflow-mastering-emmet-part-4/